# auto-generate models for sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm wanting to start using Sequelize, a module that allows ORM for mysql in node.js. I was wondering if it's possible to auto-generate the models like CakePHP does. In CakePHP, it will read the table's info, and automatically create the associations and fields with their types in the model. i'd really hate to have to completely map out all my tables by hand, as some are relatively large. Is there something out there that will do this for me? Or am I on my own to hand-type all the models out?

Comment: If you need to generatee them just once, you can use https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto I tried it on my DB (mysql), and partly worked. It imported the structure, (columns and types), but I had to add keys and associations manually. Still better than nothing. Also for some reason it worked only when I run it on localhost (on db server). BUt that might be due to some issues with some firewalls, etc.

Answer (score 31):

You can auto generate models through sequelize-auto. Just Follow the following link
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto

It will generate models of your table.

Comment: But can you  tell me how can I save relations too (i.e Foreign key info).

Comment: Hi puneet gupta Please guide Me how to get the auto generate tables in db. I got a message from my command prompt Executing Done But when I verify the database There is nothing created inside please giude @Puneet gupta I stuck more than Two days

Comment: This is a life-saving tool. Don't waste your time creating model files with sequelize-cli if you already have your database schema.

Answer (score 13):

Now you can use [sequelize-automate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-automate) to generate models automatically. `sequelize-auto` seems to be unmaintained for a long time, and the package is out-of-date.

```sh
$ npm install sequelize-automate
$ ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize-automate --help
```

For example:

```sh
$ ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize-automate -t js -h localhost -d test -u root -p root -o models
```

Comment: The note about [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) appears to be out of date since as of today that project had a commit 23 days ago while the other has a last commit many months ago. Also one project has 20 times the contributors of the other. I don't know which works better, but the assertion that sequelize-auto is not maintained seems incorrect now.

Comment: And now in 2022 sequelize-automate is closer to 2 years since the last commit and last release

Comment: As of 2024, [sequelize-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto) has 32,000+ weekly downloads and [sequelize-automate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-automate) has 528.  `sequelize-auto` also has the more recent commit.

Answer (score 4):

Sequelizer - A desktop application to export sequelize models automatically and visually.

Pretty impressive GUI client made with ElectronJS, grab here:
Source: https://github.com/andyforever/sequelizer

Comment: Sequelizer is just a GUI frondend for sequelize-auto.

Comment: GREAT GUI for Sequelizer-auto which I didn't have time to fiddle with the command line, it kept giving me errors , but with this tool , it was quite easy and practical . good answer !

Answer (score 3):

Use npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli

Use npm install --save-dev sequelize-auto

npx sequelize-auto -o "./database/models" -d -h localhost -u root -p 3306 -x '' -e mysql

Comment: Please elaborate or give reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [sync](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-sync) method for each of model

example:

```
Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
    db[modelName].sync().then(result => {
       // some logic
    }).catch(err => {
       // some logic
    })
});
```

the logic will create a new table if the table not exist

full script `index.js`

```
'use strict';
const fs        = require("fs");
const path      = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_DATEBASE, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorsAliases: false
});

const db = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js") && (file !== "migrations") && (file !== "redshift-migrations");
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }

  db[modelName].sync().then(result => {
    // some logic
  }).catch(err => {
    // some logic
  })
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

the script takes all files(models) in given directory where you will put the index.js file

the structure looks like here:

[image: structure]

Comment: They want the opposite. To generate model files from an existed database.

Answer (score 1):

see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/339

Sequelize provides methods to read the existing table names of a database. Furthermore there is a method to read the structure of a table. Combined, it should be possible to automate the creation of models.

Comment: schaweet! thanks. at least that opens up a way for me to create them myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use this website to generate laravel and node JS models from schema and db config
https://laravelschema.com/node-js-sequalize

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create auto models from existing DB.

Create a new node project using node init.

Install the sequelize-auto package using npm

```
npm install --save sequelize-auto
```

If your DB is mysql

```
npm install --save mysql2
```

Create a new file (e.g., generate-models.js) and require the necessary modules:

```
const SequelizeAuto = require('sequelize-auto');
const path = require('path');
const options = {
  dialect: 'mysql', // Replace with your database dialect (e.g., mysql, postgres, etc.)
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '3306', // Replace with your database port
  database: 'your_database_name', // Replace with your database name
  username: 'your_username', // Replace with your database username
  password: 'your_password', // Replace with your database password
  directory: path.resolve(__dirname, './models'), // Replace with the desired output directory for models
  additional: {
    timestamps: false, // Additional options for model generation (e.g., timestamps, underscored, etc.)
    underscored: true
  }
};
const auto = new SequelizeAuto(null, null, null, options);
auto.run(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(auto.tables); // List of generated tables
});
```

Save the file and run it with Node.js:

```
node generate-models.js
```