# How to Bulk insert JSON array into mysql database with sequelize without knowing its model?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a JSON array of more than 50000+ records. is there any way I can use sequelize to bulk insert the dynamic data into the database as there is no model for the sequelize object?

Comment: Are you talking about inserting into existing table(s) or also creating tables based on the JSON?

Comment: Table already exists  but there's no model as the table was dynamically made using raw query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [auto-generate models for sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501431/auto-generate-models-for-sequelize)

Comment: seems like if you want to use sequelize you should generate models from the table and use bulkInsert.  but if you are creating the table with a raw query, why not do that for the inserts too?

Comment: that's what i did bro, but my question was, 'is there a way to'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have a large array of json objects that you want to insert into mysql. Assuming the JSON structure is the same for all elements of the array, you can use `sequelize.query` after manipulating the objects into proper arrays for column names and values:

```
const colNames = Object.keys(bigArrayOfObjects[0]).map(elem => '`' + elem + '`').join(', ')

const rowValues = bigArrayOfObjects.map(row => Object.values(obj))

await sequelize.query(`
      INSERT INTO company (${colNames}) VALUES ${values.map(() => '(?)').join(',')}
    `, {
    replacements: values,
    type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT,
}
```